# Python '\n' not working when writing to txt file on Amazon Linux

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2

I have a python script which writes a to a txt log file using the following code:

```
with open('folder/log_{}.txt'.format(today), "a") as text_file:
    text_file.write(text_to_write)
```

The text_to_writeis usually a string which includes '\n' to start a new line.

It works fine when running the script locally on my windows machine. However, when a run it on an Amazon Linux instance it ignores the '\n' and all the text_to_write are on the same line. The '\n' isn't written to the log either, is it just ignored as if it wasn't there.

I can't find out why this is or how to resolve it so I can specify where to include a new line.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure *text_to_write* contains a new line character ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s really weird.

But anyway, since you want to write a text file, you should specify the character encoding:

```
text_to_write = "hello\n"
with open(path, mode="a", encoding="utf-8") as text_file:
    text_file.write(text_to_write)
```

But you can also use a logger. In your main function, you can initialize the logging configuration. For instance you can use a basic configuration:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    filename=path)
```

Of course, this configuration can be read from an `INI` file.

Then in every module you can define a logger and use it like this:

```
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

LOG.info("hello")
```

The result is something like this:

```
INFO:module_name:hello
```

### Edit

#### Clarification about **newlines**

For text stream, Python uses the concept of [*universal newline*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/):

> **universal newlines**
>   A manner of interpreting text streams in which all of the following are recognized as ending a line: the Unix end-of-line convention '\n', the Windows convention '\r\n', and the old Macintosh convention '\r'.

If you want to write Windows specific text files on a Linux system, you need to force the newline to '\r\n', this can be done like this:

```
with open(path, mode="a", encoding="utf-8", newline="\r\n") as text_file:
    text_file.write(text_to_write)
```

But, it is usually a bad practice… you’ll understand why bellow…

#### Notepad

Microsoft Notepad is not very clever: it cannot handle Unix text files correctly because it doesn’t recognize the '\n' like a newline so every line are joined together and appears like a single line of text.

I recommend you to install the famous [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) which is a smart tool and can auto-detect newline style on file opening. You can also use it to change it.

So, my advice is to use *universal newline* and install a good tool like Notepad++, or [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com), etc.

Comment: Thanks @Laurent LAPORTE. Yes it's very weird - I've added your suggestions above but it resulted in the same outcome, everything still on the same line. However, I've discovered the issues only is noticeable when viewing the files in Notepad. If I use another programme the text appears on different lines as intended, so it's not such a big problem.

Just not sure why it the output is different on notepad when the text is written from the script on my local machine (no problem) and when it is written on the Amazon Linux instance (everything on one line).

Comment: See my clarification about newlines